# Cannot connect to home wireless after upgrading to 14.04 from 13.10, still able to connect to my phone hotspot though?

Tags: wireless, upgrade, intel-wireless

I'm no longer able to connect to my home wireless since upgrading to 14.04, though my other devices still connect to it fine. The problem computer can still see all the available wireless SSID's, and I'm still able to connect to my phone hotspot.
Some details here, please let me know if there's anything else I can provide that will help!

```
[valley][assignment5]>lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)  
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)  
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)  
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)  
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)  
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)  
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)  
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)  
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)  
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QS77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)  
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)  
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)  
02:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 07)  
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 96)  
[valley][assignment5]>sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface  
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]  
       vendor: Intel Corporation  
       physical id: 0  
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0  
       logical name: wlan0  
       version: 96  
       serial: 84:3a:4b:0c:80:48  
       width: 64 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless  
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn  
       resources: irq:45 memory:f0c00000-f0c01fff  
  *-network:0 DISABLED  
       description: Ethernet interface  
       physical id: 2  
       logical name: wwan0  
       serial: ce:c4:e9:85:40:36  
       capabilities: ethernet physical  
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_mbim driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC MBIM link=no multicast=yes  
  *-network:1  
       description: Ethernet interface  
       physical id: 3  
       logical name: eth0  
       serial: 00:b5:6d:00:21:cd  
       size: 100Mbit/s  
       capacity: 100Mbit/s  
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation  
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Dec-2011 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=10.1.1.17 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

edit: FIXED! my apologies, it was a setting in my router was that incorrect, it was just a fluke that it was still working before by the looks as some of my devices worked, but I found another that didn't which helped isolate the problem!

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. If you've found the answer already, you may add it under the answer box instead adding it within the question. :)

Comment: You are encouraged to answer your own question Using the Answer box below. Your experience may help others! It won't hurt your reputation here either!